# Gitlab CI: run job only if artifact exists

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, continuous-delivery

I have monorepo and I want to run child pipeline depending on content of directory which has changed. In job `prepare_config` I check where are latest changes, I create child config yml and in next stage's job `run_child` I run child pipeline from .

The problem is, if `model-gitlab-ci.yml` doesn't exist, then job `run_child` fails instead of skipping due to missing artifact. I searched for solution to conditionally run job only if artifact exists instead of failing, but didn't found any solution. Maybe someone here have some idea?

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - .pre
  - build

prepare_config:
  stage: .pre
  tags:
    - sometag
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
      when: always
      changes:
      - '.gitlab-ci.yml'
      - 'DIR_A/**/*'
      - 'DIR_B/**/*'
      - 'DIR_C/**/*'
  script:
    - |-
      files=$(git diff-tree --name-only --no-commit-id ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA:-$CI_COMMIT_SHA})
      echo "Files changed: $files"
      for f in $files; do
        if [ -d $f ]; then
          sed "s/{{ MODEL_NAME }}/$f/g" .gitlab-ci-template.yml >> model-gitlab-ci.yml
        fi
      done
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "model-gitlab-ci.yml"

run_child:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
      when: always
  needs:
    - job: prepare_config
      artifacts: true
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: model-gitlab-ci.yml
        job: prepare_config
    strategy: depend
```

Comment: Can't you set variable in  `prepare_config` say variable as `IS_MODEL_CI_EXISTS` with 0 (i.e. no) or 1 (i.e. yes) value. Furthermore, in `run_child` check value of `IS_MODEL_CI_EXISTS` and based on that proceed with execution or skip execution of `run_child` ?

Comment: @amitd how do you want to pass that variable between stages? If you meant `rules:if` then no, it won't work because it is being evaluated once pipelineis created.

Comment: Dynamically created jobs could be a solution (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines). For creating dynamic child pipelines you could use jsonnet (https://jsonnet.org/).

Comment: @JkbLskw did you take a look at my yml? IT IS dynamic pipeline.

Comment: @Taz sure. With this kind of dynamic pipeline you cannot react to artifacts/variables created in script-sections of other jobs. With jsonnet, jobs can be created using variables in script-sections. This would help you with your problem.

Comment: @JakobLiskow How does jsonnet help with dynamic pipelines? jsonnet is strictly a template language AFAICT.

Comment: @JakobLiskow you still don't get it. The case is simple: if artifact exists, then downstream job runs, if not it does not. Neither `jsonnet`, nor any other scripting language can be solution here.

Comment: @Taz with a language like jsonnet, however, a job can be created or not based on a value. this behavior can then be used to trigger or not to trigger your generated job in your generated yaml file. Its that simple.

Comment: @Jakob Liskow if you say so, please provide answer to my question with solution you're describing.

Comment: @Taz i hope the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The job *"jsonnet"* uses jsonnet to generate a YAML file *"trigger.yml"* from the file *"trigger.jsonnet"*. If the variable in the JSONNET file `triggering == true` it contains the jobs *"artifact:helper"* and *"trigger"*. If `triggering == false` it contains the job *"not:triggered"*, which runs empty.

The job *"artifact:helper"* is required so that the generated file *"generated.yml"* can be transferred to the trigger as an artifact. If a trigger job in a child pipeline wanted to use an artifact of the parent pipeline directly, a cross-dependency exception would occur.

The job *"trigger"* in the YAML file *"trigger.yml"* ultimately triggers the job *"template_job"* from *"generated.yml"*.

**Jobs `if triggering == true`**

[image]

**Jobs `if triggering == false`**

[image]

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
jsonnet:
  image: jkblskw/jsonnet:jsonnet-curl
  stage: .pre
  script:
    # do something
    - if [ "$TEST_TRIGGER" = true ]; then TRIGGERING=true && cp template.yml generated.yml; else TRIGGERING=false; fi
    - jsonnet --ext-code triggering=$TRIGGERING --ext-code pipeline_id=$CI_PIPELINE_ID trigger.jsonnet > trigger.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - trigger.yml
      - generated.yml

trigger:
  stage: build 
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: trigger.yml
        job: jsonnet
    strategy: depend
```

**trigger.jsonnet**

```
local triggering = std.extVar("triggering");
local pipeline_id = std.extVar("pipeline_id");

if triggering then 
{
    ["artifact:helper"]: {
        stage: "build",
        variables: {
            PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: pipeline_id
        },
        needs:{
            pipeline: "$PARENT_PIPELINE_ID",
            job: "jsonnet"
        },
        script: "echo 'Job needs to be executed in order for the artifact to be triggered. A trigger in the same job throws a cross-reference exception.'",
        artifacts: {
            paths: ["generated.yml"]
        }
    },
    ["trigger"]: {
        stage: "test",
        needs: ["artifact:helper"],
        trigger: {
            include: {
                artifact: "generated.yml",
                job: "artifact:helper"
            },
            strategy: "depend"
        }
    } 
}else
{
    ["not:triggered"]: {
        stage: "build",
        script: "echo 'no further triggering'"
    } 
}
```

**template.yml**

```
template_job:
  stage: test
  script: 
      - echo "running template_job"
```